# Getting error while put this code in my controller class: "no suitable constructor found for keyframe"

Tags: javafx

Getting error in the below mentioned section:

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import static com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.ExsltDatetime.time;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;  

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    Timeline clock = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> {  /*getting error here*/          
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    time.setText(hour + ":" + (minute) + ":" + second);
    }),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1));/*getting error here for seconds(1)*/
    );
    clock.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    clock.play();
    }
```

Comment: Don't you just have a stray `;` at the end of the call to the second `KeyFrame` constructor?

Comment: its showing for `seconds(1)` methods and in the first section its showing *no suitable constructor found for keyframe*

Comment: Did you delete the `;` that shouldn't be there?

Comment: delete that but still showing *can't find symbol seconds(1)* and *no suitable constructor found for keyframe*

Comment: Oh, you also have the wrong import for `Duration`. You need `javafx.util.Duration`.

Comment: thanks a lot its working